# Interactive image in Android

Tags: android, image, dictionary

How to make images interactive in android?

Consider the following image:

[image]

What should be done so that if I select any point(A,B or C) in the picture I should be able to  change the color of that particular dot? Can this be achieved by using x,y co-ordinates in the image ?

And also if I select A and then B, the path should be highlighted between A and B.

Kindly provide me details on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

there are so many ways to achieve it. here's what i can think of:

1. using openGL . even here, you can use third party libraries like libgdx or andEngine.
2. create a custom imageView that will draw those lines and circles on the onDraw() method. also calculate the location of the touches etc...
3. the [imageLayout library](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout) might be able to help you.

Comment: Is there anything new that could be used to achieve this? Any libraries or anything I'm missing?

Comment: Absolutely nothing... I even upvoted your answer... But it's been 1 1/2 years now and maybe there are new possibilities to achieve that? That was my question...